# converting mysql query into spring JPA query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following mysql query that I want to convert to SPring JPA.

```
SELECT * FROM SERVER s WHERE s.COMPLETE_DT BETWEEN (DATE_SUB('2014-11-07 16:30:20', INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)) 
AND (DATE_SUB('2014-11-07 16:30:20', INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))
```

I am doing it the following way

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Server s WHERE s.completeDt BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(%?1%, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)) AND (DATE_SUB(%?1%, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)))
List<Server> findDate(Date dt);
```

but getting an error

> "Interval" not recognized

Comment: There are many jpql docs on the web. None will have date_sub, or interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Data you could use a query like :

```
List<Server> findByCompleteDtBetween(final LocalDateTime startDate, final LocalDateTime endDate);
```

And compute startDate and endDate in your service to fit the targeted interval.

See more : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation